# What's up with this 'Unknown at rule @use' error, do I need a plugin/ some particular set-up besidess sass compiler?

Tags: css, sass, partials

So, I've done making all of my partials at there own folder(like base,abstracts etc) and every folder have there _index.scss where I already @forward all the partials there. Then at the main.scss file, the only thing I needed to do is @use all of my folders' index. But, instead of showing all the results at the css file, it just copies the @use comment from the main sass file, and return with the 'Unknown at rule @use', this makes sense because @use only works for sass not css. But why does the css doesnt translate the @use function from the main sass file, instead it just spit out the exact code block which is " @use 'abstracts' "(for example). Do I need to set-up something besides the sass compiler itself? Like some javascript? Because I dont really have any decent knowledge at Javascript. I hope you can answer my questions, Thank You!!

[This is the screenshot, the right side is the css, which suppose to load the sass files,but instead just output the same command which is the @use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeZIW.png)